# How are connections managed in Flyway command line?

Tags: java, database, flyway

I couldn't find this in the docs (and am too lazy to read the code) - does Flyway CL use a single connection for the entire task, including callbacks?

Specifically, I'd like to know if I can use `beforeMigrate` (or `beforeEachMigrate`) to set database session parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two connections: one for the metadata table and one for the migrations. So yes, your assumption should work.